# Vkontakte UserAPI examples on C++

Tags: c++, api, vk

Say me please, where i can find examples on C++ with using UserAPI Vkontakte?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261431/where-can-i-find-api-for-vk-com-in-c

Comment: =))))
I think there are no users in stackoverflow.com, who used vkontakte.ru :)

Comment: I'm using vkontakte once in a while ;p

Comment: But there are many users who use vk.com =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[libvkext](http://code.google.com/p/libvkext/) on google code seems to be one, you can also try to [search](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:vkontakte) google codebase for more...